# Failure to install kernlab package R.

Tags: r, package, failed-installation

I know other people have asked this question... but no one has really offered a solution.

I am trying to install the Kernlab R package, and I get this:

.....

```
install.packages("kernlab")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/kernlab_0.9-19.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2029405 bytes (1.9 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 1.9 Mb

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 1978368 != reported length 2029405
Warning in install.packages :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'kernlab/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

........
```

I tried downloading the zip file and opening it from the computer, but it says that the files from the CRAN repository are corrupted. I tried winrar, unzipping the folder, etc.

I have to use this for the Data Analysis Coursera course and posted the question there. No one has answered yet.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Felipe

Comment: Did you try using a different CRAN mirror?

Comment: Or from source: `install.packages("kernlab", type="source")`

Comment: I tried using a different mirror and it still didnt work...I also tried the psych packages and a few others, and it tells me that the files are corrupted

Comment: Have you tried restarting R?

Comment: Yes. I restarted R, restarted the computer, etc... it simply says that the files are corrupted. It doesn't matter what mirror I use... Is it possible that it is my computer?

Comment: I think we need session info.  Use `sessionInfo()` and post the results back to your original question.  You may have a corrupt version of R.  You may want to try deleting R and re installing it.

Comment: If manually opening the zip file doesn't work, and you tried different mirror sites, that suggests the problem is indeed with your computer. Or maybe your internet connection. You could try getting someone else to download the zip and give it to you on a USB stick.

Answer (score 3):

To install kernlab package: [Download](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html) the kernlab binaries for your OS. Then open a terminal and type:

```
$R CMD INSTALL kernlab_0.9-19.tar
```

Then go to R and use it directly by issuing the command:

```
library(kernlab)
```

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded from 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html
and unrar in:
Documents Folder\R\win-library\3.2\kernlab
and ready.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, tried installing the package on the R console and not R studio and then use the package in R studio. Now sure why or how it works, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue on EC2

Installed after I made a few links.

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

ln -s /usr/lib64/R/modules/lapack.so /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

ln -s /usr/lib64/libblas.so /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

ln -s /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0 /usr/lib64/R/lib/libgfortran.so

ln -s /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib64/R/lib/libquadmath.so

Answer (score 0):

I just tried installing in RStudio; it works fine:

`install.packages("kernlab")`

Here is my version of RStudio:

```
Version 0.99.489 – © 2009-2015 RStudio, Inc.
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues in the past.  This error can occur when the "login" information is unset for R, in which case you may not have the right permissions for /tmp/ What does your Sys.info() response look like? If you have login as "unknown", you can get said permission errors.  Example:

```
                                   sysname 
                                   "Linux" 
                                   release 
                                 <release>
                                   version 
                             <version info>
                                  nodename 
                                    <nodename> 
                                   machine 
                                  "x86_64" 
                                     login 
                                   "unknown"
                                      user 
                                   <your name> 
                            effective_user 
                                   <your name>
```

You can set the login through making sure R is being passed the correct user / uid.  You can often set this info in `.conf` files for tools such as Rstudio, Rserve, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this one eventually... My laptop at the time had a really weird virus that wouldn't let me install anything, even packages.

It was a really old laptop, but I basically removed the virus from the PC, and I got it work.